# Realtek RTL8723be Wifi and Bluetooth 14.04

Tags: networking, bluetooth, realtek

I just installed the OS on my laptop and at first wifi didn't work. After connecting to ethernet and updating everything, the wifi is working. But it disconnects here and there and requires me to reload the service or reboot. The bluetooth on the card does not work at all. It is seen and hciconfig shows an address for it. However, I cannot find bluetooth devices with it. I have seen a lot of different posts with this card but most of them are older. Where can I go from here.

Answer (score 1):

I made a ppa with bluetooth driver for this chip.

It is tested and works. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms linux-firmware
```

It will stay after kernel updates.

Answer (score 0):

For the WiFi disconnection problem the following fix worked for me:

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

A window will open, add the following lines

```
#Prevents the WiFi card from automatically sleeping and halting connection
options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0
```

As for the bluetooth not finding devices I haven't find a solution yet. Hope that helps.