# Yet another "Internet is not working fine on 14.04" question.

Tags: 14.04, internet, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my brand new laptop and got this annoying behavior: wireless connection works fine the first minutes and then it just stops working at all. Network manager says it is still connected, other devices works properly and ifconfig has a normal output. I have to reboot and after it Internet starts working fine again, at least for some minutes.

Comment: What wifi hardware are you using? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/538545/edit) the output of `lshw -C network` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help :[Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)
It contains many command line commands that might help

Answer (score 0):

After a brief search I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516127/realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-and-bluetooth-14-04). Please feel free to delete this question that I find a bit useless due to lack of information.